# PHP using mysql need to calculate the total cost of all dropdown boxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have multiple dropdown boxes and they have a price inside the drop down box and I want to gather all the prices of each dropdown box and echo it as a total price. So far I have managed to echo the price but it's only displaying the last product of each dropdown box so it doesn't change price when the user selects different products.

```
        <?php
      //PSU QUERY
  $sqlpsu="SELECT id, psu, price, psuWATT FROM  PSU";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlpsu);

    echo "<select name='psu'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["psu"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';
        $pricePsu = $row["price"];
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: My submission hand in is like in a few days i don't have time for that

Comment: Do you  have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Better hope and pray you don't have to deploy this on PHP 7 because it won't work. I'm just looking out for you here.

Comment: my teacher said using mysql_query is completely fine

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: What your teacher says and what's actually "fine" are apparently two different things, and sadly many educators are five to ten years out of date in their thinking. I do hope you can figure this out, I'm not sure what the issue is specifically, but if you have time later read up on [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) which addresses common mistakes like this.

Comment: the issue is that when the page is loaded the variable only echos the last record of the table rather then the product that is selected in the dropdown box

Answer (score 1):

before while set

```
$pricePsu = 0;
```

in the while use

```
$pricePsu += $row["price"];
```

After while `echo "$pricePsu"`

Option html

```
<select name="psu" id="psu" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1" price="5">option1 $5</option>
  <option value="2" price="10">option2 $10</option>
  <option value="3" price="15">option3 $15</option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Option javascript

```
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var str = "";
    $( "#psu option:selected" ).each(function() {
      total += parseInt($( this ).attr("price")) ;
    });
    $( "div" ).text( total );
  })
  .trigger( "change" );
```

Example!
https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/epxvhfyh/

Good practice:

```
echo "<option value='{$row['id']}' price='{$row['price']}'>{$row['psu']} £ {$row['price']}</option>";
```

Comment: I read wrong.. if you get a total cost while user select, need to use javascript or jquery. And if you use select, set select as multiselect option.

Comment: that just adds all the products for that dropdown box that's not what i want i need to just get the price of what option the user selects. Then at the bottom i will add up all the variables and echo the total price because there is multiple dropdown boxes.

Comment: @bill186 You have to do something :)

Comment: I have tried in my code i tried storing $row['price']; into a variable then echoing it but it only displays the price of the last record in that table which is useless

Comment: when you use while and set value $pricePsu = $row["price"] in each iteration, the variable $pricePsu have value of the last iteration.

Comment: So how do i give the $pricePsu the selected interation so it has the value of the selected interation

Comment: Your javascript doesn't work because its trying to look for price when my data is from $row["price"] but i tried that and it won't work

Comment: first, you need import jquery. Second, show me your code where try to set price in the option. My code works, check the example.

Comment: And check that the javascript works with select with id = psu

Comment: the price is coming from $row['price] which is from a database ['price'] is the field name